# Class Not Found Exception When object implements Parcelable

Tags: android

I'm trying to pass custom object between two activities, the custom object has array list of objects and both of them are implementing parcelable interface. When trying to read array list of objects the object from index 1 onwards is null and am getting an error as Class Not Found Exception.

Note: am using createTypedArrayList and writeTypedArrayList respectively to read and write from parcel any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeTypedList(_devices);
}

private SomeClass(Parcel in) {
    in.readTypedList(_devices, SomeClass.CREATOR);
}
```

all code details you may found [here](http://qaru.site/questions/80348/how-to-properly-implement-parcelable-with-an-arraylistparcelable).

> P.S. You can write/read only primitive type with Parcelable. Do not look at the language, just read the code :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have resolved the issue createTypedList works in my case, the order in which i read and write the attributes for marshalling and un marshalling was not proper so i faced this issue. Thanks for the reply